# Using Sessions in PHP with Oracle 11g R2 (11.0.2)

Tags: php, oracle11g

I have a form like this: The file name is "main.php"

```
 <html>

    <form action = "options.php" method = "POST" />
        <p> <h3> Enter Phone Number: </h3> <input type = "text" name = 
 "cust_phone" />
        <p> <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
    </form>
  </html>
```

The "options.php" looks like this:

```
      <html>
      <body> Details of: <?php session_start();
       echo htmlentities($_POST["cust_phone"]) . "<br>";
       $link = oci_connect('hd','hd', 'localhost/mydb');
       if(!$link) {
          $e = oci_error();
          exit('Connection error    ' . $e['message']);
        }
       $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST["cust_phone"];
       echo $_SESSION['var'];
       $ph = htmlentities($_POST["cust_phone"]);
       $q1 = "select CUST_ID from customer where CUST_PHONE = :bv_ph";
       $q1parse = oci_parse($link, $q1);
       oci_bind_by_name($q1parse, ':bv_ph', $ph);

    oci_execute($q1parse);
    oci_fetch($q1parse);
    $res = oci_result($q1parse, 'CUST_ID');
    if(!$res) {
        echo "No Order found. New Order?";
    }
    ?>
    <form action = "" method = "POST" >
        <input type = "radio" name = "option" value = "Yes" checked> Yes 
    <br>
        <input type = "radio" name = "option" value ="No"> No <br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
    </form>
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['option']) && ($_POST['option']) == "Yes") {
                header("Location: newcustomer.php");
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['option']) && ($_POST['option']) == "No") {
            header("location: main.php");
        }

    ?>
   </body>
```

The "newcustomer.php" looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action = "order.php" method = "POST" >
    <p> Phone Number: </p>

    <p> Enter Address: <input type = "text" name = "address" /></p>
    <p> Enter Area: <input type = "text" name = "area" /></p>
    </form>
    <?php
             session_start();
         echo $_SESSION ['var'];
        ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the value of the number entered by the user in "main.php" to be used in "newcustomer.php" which I am not able to achieve. Am i using the session variable correctly? The result when I run "newcustomer.php" does not show any error but does not echo the "$_SESSION['var']".

Answer (score 0):

You should write session_start() every page topper ...

```
<?php 
  session_start();
?>
<html>
 .....
 ......
```

Comment: I did it. It's still not working. It works within the same file "options.php" but does not in "newcustomer.php".

Comment: you should aslo session_start() in newcustomer.php

Comment: I did in all the files. Still there is no error but it's not displaying.

Comment: try with a online hosting server . sometimes its problem in localhost .. And tell me about error message

Comment: There is no error message. It just doesn't display as if it's ignored!!

Comment: Bhai there is no error. The echo doesn't work that's it.

Comment: print your session like this print_r($_SESSION); And from where its come $_POST["cust_phone"] ?

Comment: It comes from the main.php where the no. Is entered the first time. Then carried to options.php using post and then finally I want in newcustomer.php. Can you give the code how its  done? I started the session in al three files but still its usable only in options.php and not displayed in newcustomer.php.

Comment: in options.php  ....... just write session_start() in top before html tag . and then $_SESSION['var'] = "putsomevar" ; write like this . and print newcustomer.php. print_r($_SESSION)

Comment: Ok il try it and get back.

Comment: Its not working :(.  

    `<?php  
      session_start();  
    ?>  
   <html>  
  <body>  
  <?php  
  if(!isset($_SESSION['var'])) {   
   echo "variable not set";  
  }  
  print_r($_SESSION);  
  ?>`

Comment: The Output I get is this:

`Array ( [var] => )`

`Phone Number:`

`Enter Address:` 

`Enter Area:`